# Removing a category from boxplot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a boxplot on a dataframe with characters (factor levels removed while importing the dataframe using 'stringsAsFactors = FALSE' command). Here is the sample code for my plot:

```
boxplot(df$H~df$C, outline=F, na.rm = T, ylab="H", xlab="C", main="H by C", ylim=c(min(df$H),max(df$H)))
```

The problem is that one of categories on the x axis is a '0' which I would like to remove. Is there a way to prevent this category from being plotted?

Comment: just set the correct `at` to `NA`: `boxplot(H ~ C, df, at = c(NA, 1, 2))` or `boxplot(H ~ C, df, at = c(1, NA, 2))` etc

Comment: @rawr worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming df$C is the field containing categorical values of "0" that you want to exclude, you can create a new data frame that you then use to plot.

```
# exclude records with df$C value equal to 0
nonzero_df = df[df$C != "0"]

# produce boxplot
boxplot(nonzero_df$H~df$C, outline=F, na.rm = T, ylab="H", xlab="C", main="H by C", ylim=c(min(nonzero_df$H),max(nonzero_df$H)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to drop the `0` level:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("A", "A", "A", "0", "B", "0", "B"),
  v2 = c(12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78)
)
```

Solution:

```
df2 <- droplevels(df[-which(df$v1=="0"), ]) # drop level
boxplot(df2$v2 ~ df2$v1)
```

[image]